# Auto Arrangement and Positioning of nested containers

Tags: python, c#, math, autolayout, area

We are trying to solve a problem of auto-layout or auto-arrangements of containers. The containers can be in a hierarchy and can be defined by the rules below:

- All shapes are containers - Rectangle or Square
- Each container can have 1 or more child containers, and so on.
- Some containers can be without any child containers.

#### Data Format

- Height
- Width
- X
- Y
- ChildContainers

For the sake of solving this problem, we can set the height, width to `3000*3000`, and position to `0, 0`.
Solution so far:

We have tried solving the solution by the following steps:

1. Calculate Area (H * W)
2. Count number of child containers
3. Divide Area / By Number of Child Containers

We get equal area for child containers. Now we need to calculate `Height, Width & X, Y` for child containers inside the container.
We tried calculating this by calculating factors, but are not able to get any further than that.

I have tagged this with Python / C# because I can create the solution using any of them.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: Let me add code.